# How do I get all those tabs to be the same in upgrades

Tags: add-on

I have Blender 2.78 in the Tools shelf area it has all these tabs: Tools Create Relations Animation Physics Grease Pencil 3D Printing Navigation Layers Bool Tools Archimesh Sketchfab Measureit Sculpt

These tabs aren't in Version 2.79 How do I easily make them transfer from 2.78 to 2.79?

Thank You.

Comment: Hi, those tabs are available in any blender version, some of them depend on the installed addons and/or on the current scene mode/view... and, of course, to see them you must have the toolbox visible. Try adding a screenshot of that part of you blender 2.79 window (use the question image button to ad the screenshot file)

Answer (score 2):

Those are addons. Whether they're enabled or not is stored in the startup file which is stored in your settings for Blender (e.g. for Windows: %APPDATA%/Roaming/Blender Foundation/Blender/[version]/).

When you install a new version on the splash screen there will be a "Copy Previous Settings" button. That should copy everything from the previous version and the folder for the previous version will remain just in case.

If the option isn't available (because you might have saved some settings and created a 2.79 folder), you can just delete the 2.79 folder, start Blender, and the option should be there now.

You could alternatively go into the User Preferences > Add-ons and re-enable the ones you want, one by one, but any options you might have changed then saved to the startup file will not be there.

I have also just copied the files manually. Probably not the best idea, but it has worked.